# jQuery onunload do action if button was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small website who's client side framework is *jQuery*.

I have a page where I need to do some *AJAX* action before the page unloads but that action may not fire if a certain button was clicked.

I was trying this with:

```
<body onbeforeunload="myaction();">
```

But how do I know that certain button was clicked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `onbeforeunload` into `jQuery` also:

```
myCounter = true;
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#mytest').bind('click', function(){
        myCounter = false;
    });
});
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if (myCounter) {
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'mytest.php'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var globalClickVariable = false;

$('#my-button').click(function() {
    globalClickVariable = true;
});

<body onbeforeunload="if(!globalClickVariable) { myaction(); }">
```